# Can I limit concurrent requests using GCD?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm acquiring data from a database asynchronously. Is there any way I can limit the concurrent requests to a number, but still execute the rest?

I saw [a post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) using NSOperation and NSOperationQueue
but this is too complicated for me.
Is there any other ways to do it?
Can GCD achieve it?

Comment: I would say that using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` is easier than using GCD directly. `NSOperationQueue` has a very handy `maxConcurrentOperationsCount` property. With GCD, you will need to implement your own counter of some sort. You could for instance use the `dispatch_semaphore` family of functions...

Comment: @Guillaume Do you have a sample code I can see? I've read a tutorial and class reference, and still don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 17):

Something like this:

```
...
//only make one of these obviously :) remaking it each time you dispatch_async wouldn't limit anything
dispatch_semaphore_t concurrencyLimitingSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(limit);
...
//do this part once per task, for example in a loop
dispatch_semaphore_wait(concurrencyLimitingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_async(someConcurrentQueue, ^{
    /* work goes here */
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(concurrencyLimitingSemaphore);
}
```

Comment: For more details, see Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091), specifically the section [Using Dispatch Semaphores to Regulate the Use of Finite Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24).

Comment: Wouldn't placing `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` call just before (and outside of) `dispatch_async()` be better / more efficient?

Comment: An yes, then we need to wrap the loop in `dispatch_async()`. This way we'll have _just one_ task on top of the currently running instead of all N at the same time.

Comment: @werediver Actually, it would not just be better, it would alleviate the chance for a deadlock, due to when threads get exhausted. In this solution, when the resource maximum is hit, any further attempt to submit a block will create a new thread. This goes on until the thread limit is reached - and then the app _may_ deadlock.

Comment: Yeah, 2013-me apparently wasn't thinking about thread exhaustion issues as much. If someone wants to edit that in feel free, or I'll try to get to it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution for limited concurrent execution of **synchronous** tasks:

```
func dispatch_async_batch(tasks: [() -> ()], limit: Int, completion: (() -> ())?) {
    if tasks.count > 0 || completion != nil {
        let q = dispatch_queue_create("dispatch_async_batch", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
        let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(limit);

        dispatch_async(q, {
            for task in tasks {
                dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
                dispatch_async(q, {
                    task()
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
                })
            }

            if let completion = completion {
                dispatch_barrier_async(q, completion)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This approach has small overhead: only one extra task is put on the queue (i.e. one extra thread) aside the currently executing ones. It's especially good when you have big overall amount of tasks.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/werediver/a7cc14177f67e52ff67fbeaf37acb55c) is a ready to use demo, just put the code into a playground.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way is to set up n serial queues

```
struct dataCalls {
    let n:Int
    func fetchIt(){
        print ("Done",n)
    }

    init(n:Int){
        self.n=n
    }
}

var dataCallsArray: [dataCalls]=[]
var qArray:[dispatch_queue_t] = []
let n = 5
for i in 1...50 {
    dataCallsArray.append(dataCalls(n:i))
}

for _ in 1...n {
    qArray.append(dispatch_queue_create(nil, nil))
}

var i = 0
for data in dataCallsArray {
    dispatch_async(qArray[i%n], {() -> Void in data.fetchIt()})
    i++
}
```

Comment: Note this won't load balance between the queues if some fall further behind than others.