# Download Multiple File at a time in Swift

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I was finally able to download 1 video from a server using the following code:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLConnectionDelegate {


    var file:NSFileHandle?

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadVideo()
    }





    func downloadVideo(sender: UIButton) {

        let urlPath: String = "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
        connection.start()

    }


    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {


        var fileName = "test.mov"

        var fileAtPath = fileInDocumentsDirectory(fileName)
        if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileAtPath) == false)
        {
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(fileAtPath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        }

         file = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileAtPath)!

        if ((file) != nil){
              file!.seekToEndOfFile()
         }


    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){

        //write,each,data,received
        if(data != nil){


           if((file) != nil){

            file!.seekToEndOfFile()

            }

          file!.writeData(data)


        }


    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {

         file!.closeFile()
    }



    func documentsDirectory() -> String {

        let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

        return documentsFolderPath
    }


    func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String{
    return documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

But I need to download a lot of video files(I have at least 100 URL), how can I do it? I was thinking of doing it one at a time but I guess that in that approach I will have a lot of NSURLConnections instances and maybe I will eat all my RAM, Can you please help me to learn the right form of multiple files download?

Thank you so much!

Comment: if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileAtPath) == false) change to  if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileAtPath) { ... }

Comment: Thanks, old Java habits xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a concurrent queue to limit the max number of connections at a time.

```
func downloadVideo(sender: UIButton) {
    for urlPath in urlPaths {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)) {
            var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
            var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
            connection.start()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to customize the max number of connections, check here:
[Can I limit concurrent requests using GCD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394014/can-i-limit-concurrent-requests-using-gcd)

Comment: Hi @Yoichi , in this approach I can Still use the other functions for all of my urlpaths?:(didReceiveResponse,didReceiveData,connectionDidFinishLoading)

I mean all of my video downlads connections will use the same functions ?

Thanks!

Comment: `connection` argument has `originalRequest` property, and can get its URL, so I think all didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData, connectionDidFinishLoading can get the request URL to handle in the methods.