# Downloading images serially in a serial queue very slow

Tags: ios, json, swift, grand-central-dispatch

**Requirement** **-** I have a requirement in which I am receiving a JSON dictionary from which I am retrieving an array of images and content text. Then I have to display all the images with corresponding contents in a collection view.

***Update -*** Above all I need to calculate the cell size based on image size scaled to the a constant width for which I fell that(may not be correct) I need all images to be downloaded completely then reload collection view

**Problem -** But the problem is that when I download the images in background thread and populate in separate arrays.Then the image cannot be added in the same order as they were in the JSON Dictionary since I am downloading them in a concurrent queue.

**My Solution -** So I thought of downloading them by putting everything in a serial queue which has made my retrieving data very slow. ***What can be an efficient alternative for this?***

**Code -**

```
let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("my serial queue", nil)

            dispatch_async(serialQueue, {

                print("This is first Method")

                for var i=0;i<self.resultArr.count;i++//resultArr is my array of data's in the jsonDic
             {



                    sleep(2)

                    print(self.resultArr[i].valueForKey("profile_pic")! as! String)
                    if self.resultArr[i].valueForKey("profile_pic")! as! String != "Null" && self.resultArr[i].valueForKey("profile_pic")! as! String != "null" && self.resultArr[i].valueForKey("profile_pic")! as! String != "NULL" && self.resultArr[i].valueForKey("profile_pic")! as! String != ""
                    {
                        let imageUrl = UrlClass.imageUrlWithoutExtension + String(self.resultArr[i].valueForKey("profile_pic")!)
                        print(imageUrl)
                        let url = NSURL(string: imageUrl)
                        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

                        self.contentlabelArr.insertObject(String(self.resultArr[i].valueForKey("content")!), atIndex: i)

                        if imageData != nil && imageData?.length > 0
                        {
                            print("this is \(i) image")
                            print(UIImage(data: imageData!))

                            self.imageArr.insertObject(UIImage(data: imageData!)!, atIndex: i)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print("\(i) image has nill")
                            self.imageArr.insertObject(UIImage(named: "logo.png")!, atIndex: i)
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("\(i) image has nill")
                        self.contentlabelArr.insertObject(String(self.resultArr[i].valueForKey("content")!), atIndex: i)
                        self.imageArr.insertObject(UIImage(named: "logo.png")!, atIndex: i)
                    }

                    print("\(i) times 5 is \(i * 5)")

                    if self.imageArr.count==self.resultArr.count
                    {
                         print(self.resultArr.count)
                         print(self.imageArr.count)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                            {
                                print(self.resultArr.count)
                                print(self.imageArr.count)
                                print(self.imageArr)
                                print(self.contentlabelArr)
                                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                        })
                    }
```

Comment: Of course it's slow, because you're waiting 2 seconds in each iteration. It's highly recommended to use `NSURLSession` and `NSOperationQueue` like the in sample code of Apple rather than `NSData(contentsOfURL:)`

Comment: @vadian But I need all images to come as in the same order in the resultArr. NSUrlSession is by default asynchronous and process should be run in concurrent queue,But If i do that concurrently then the order of image in array disrupts. So any code or referrals would be pretty helpful.

Comment: Set the property `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue` to `1` and you will get the same order. Or as mentioned in Oleg's answer use a data model with a custom class then the download order doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you definitely can keep the order if you use a concurrent queue. i think your code as it stands pretty much doesnt use the queue correctly at all (and why is there a `sleep(2)`?) your concurrent queue should be inside the forloop so it can fire off the different blocks at the same time, and they will use the correct index of the for loop that was assigned to them to place the resulting image in the correct array location

```
let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(2); //depending how many downloads you want to go at once
for i in 0..<self.resultArr.count {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        //download images here, order of execution will not be guaranteed, but after they are finished, they will always put the images in the array at 'i' so it doesnt matter

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    })
}
```

Comment: I will try as u have said but as you know that concurrent queue returns the completed results first despite their order of addition into the queue so how can the images be in a order. Eg - image1 is of more size than image2 then image2 will be returned first and added to array in 0 index rather than image1.

Comment: Say you fire off downloading image1 image2 image3 at the same time, but iOS decides to process them like image2 image1 image3, this is fine, because inside your code, image1 is always assigned to arrayIndex1, image2 is always assigned to arrayIndex2 etc, so the order of execution doesnt matter, just the end result of the array

Comment: I'd suggest to limit maximum concurrent downloads to a reasonable number using semaphore.

Comment: @G.Abhisek Take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14555588/3541063 (I'd put `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` call just before (and outside of) `dispatch_async()`).

Comment: ive updated my answer to show how to use the semaphores. can take a look at the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) for more info on it

Comment: @werediver if the wait was outside of the dispatch_async, it would block the for loop, which if it was on the main thread it would freeze the app for a while

Comment: @Fonix Right, but then we can wrap the loop in `dispatch_async()` and have _just one_ task on top of the currently running (downloading) instead of all N at the same time.

Comment: @G.Abhisek there was some errors in my code, ive fixed them and neatened it up a bit

Comment: Semaphores are not needed at all when creating the data source array once in the proper order and then load / update everything asynchronously. That's exactly the way Apple recommends in the sample project to update table view cells dynamically.

Comment: @vadian, it is not compulsory, but if you are downloading 1000 images at the same time, it would probably be better to download a few at a time instead of all at once

Comment: @werediver actually you wouldnt be able to have the dispatch_async around the whole for loop, because the downloading code in his code is blocking, so then the for loop will only execute 1 download at a time, instead of x at a time (or all at the same time if he wanted)

Comment: @Fonix Of course. The sample project I mean ([LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)) loads only the images of the visible cells respectively.

Comment: @Fonix I would be able to run async loop to populate async tasks for downloading images.

Comment: @werediver i only saw now that this is for a collection view now, then yes loading the images on the fly as the cells come into view would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @werediver I don't feel that we can do that in my scenario as I have a situation in which I need to calculate the cell sizes also depending the images. You can please check my updated part of the question.

Comment: @G.Abhisek ok, then this solution should be fine then... have you had the chance to test it yet? (also if there are only a few images ever, i wouldnt bother with the semiphore, but if you dont know how many there could be, then i would use it)

Comment: @Fonix No the data is dynamic, who knows what the client wants, its better to make it as dynamic. i haven't implemented. I will try it now and update you.

Comment: @vadian I have the requirement for which I need the images before the population because my cell sizes vary as per the image size and I have to calculate the cell sizes at sizeForItemAtIndexPath. So its obvious that I can't go for lazy loading of images.

Comment: @Fonix This solution finally worked but I have to implement werediver suggestion to put dispatch_semaphore_wait() call just before (and outside of) dispatch_async())

Comment: @G.Abhisek glad to hear, ye you can put it outside if this for loop is not executed on the main thread, then its affectively the same thing.

Comment: @Fonix Actually see as the code goes I am doing as running the for loop(on the main thread)->dispatch_semaphore_wait()->dispatch_async() . Earlier it was - for loop(on the main thread)->dispatch_semaphore_wait()->dispatch_async() . but in the later case (as it was suggested by you)the app was crashing due to array OutOf bounds exception.

Comment: thats strange, out of bounds doesnt seem like it would be related to this, but its probably because the array was being modified before the last thread is executed, but if the way you are doing it now prevents that then just stick to that i guess heh

Comment: ya correct I also think that is the same cause as u said -"the array was being modified before the last thread is executed". But why did the 2nd flow worked i.e put dispatch_semaphore_wait() call just before (and outside of) dispatch_async()).

Comment: because the way that doesnt crash doesnt exit the for loop before all the threads have ended, the for loop gets stuck while it waits for the threads to free up the semaphore, while my suggestions lets all the threads queue up, and the for loop exits, then the threads execute themselves when they can without the for loops help, if you get what i mean

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient way would be to create a data model object which will represent you image link and the optional UIImage. Something like this:

```
class NetworkImage {
    let imageURL: String!
    let image: UIImage?
}
```

Now when you receive your JSON with image links array, you can create your data model array, which will respect the order:

```
let dataModel: [NetworkImage]
```

So when you will retrieve your images asynchronously, you can update your dataModel with your image, so no order will be affected.
The idea can be evolved suiting your needs.
You should never use sync operations for this kind of jobs.

Comment: agree with you, i think a combination of our answers would lead to a very readable and efficient solution

Comment: seems quite interesting, will implement and try to update you.

Answer (score 1):

You may play around with this sample solution, utilising dispatch groups:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Dispatch
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


class Record {
    init(text: String, imageURL: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.image = nil
    }
    var text: String
    var imageURL: String
    var image: String?
}

extension Record: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "text: \(text), imageURL: \(imageURL), image: \(image)"
    }
}

// Fetch text and image url, but no image.
func fetchRecords(completion: ([Record]?, ErrorType?) -> ()) {
    let delayInNanoSeconds = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayInNanoSeconds, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
        let result: [Record] = [
            Record(text: "Aaa", imageURL: "path/image1"),
            Record(text: "Bbb", imageURL: "path/image2"),
            Record(text: "Ccc", imageURL: "path/image3")
        ]
        completion(result, nil)
    }
}

// fetch an image
func fetchImage(url: String, completion: (String?, ErrorType?) -> () ) {
    let delayInNanoSeconds = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayInNanoSeconds, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
        let image = url
        completion(image, nil)
    }
}

// Put everything together: 
// 1) Fetch an array of records, omitting the image
// 2) When this is finished, in parallel, for each record 
//    fetch each image.
// 3) When all is finished, call the completion handler containing
//    the records including the images
func fetchRecordsWithImages(completion: ([Record]?, ErrorType?) -> () ) {
    fetchRecords { (result, error) in
        if let records = result {
            let grp = dispatch_group_create()
            records.forEach { record in
                dispatch_group_enter(grp)
                fetchImage(record.imageURL) { (image, error) in
                    if let image = image {
                        record.image = image
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(grp)
                }
            }
            dispatch_group_notify(grp, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)) {
                completion(records, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}



fetchRecordsWithImages() { (records, error) in
    if let records = records {
        print("Records: \(records)")
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Records: [text: Aaa, imageURL: path/image1, image: Optional("path/image1"), text: Bbb, imageURL: path/image2, image: Optional("path/image2"), text: Ccc, imageURL: path/image3, image: Optional("path/image3")]
```

Comment: You don't need a group for that, just `dispatch_barrier_async()` will be enough.

Comment: @werediver No, it's not, because the task submitted to the queue is _asynchronous_. `dispatch_barrier_async` would work as a sentinel only iff the submitted blocks are synchronous.

Comment: By the way, this approach is a worked out example of @OlegDanu 's suggestion.

Comment: It is possible to run batch of async tasks limiting the number of concurrent tasks and using barrier for overall completion handler. I can extract a sample from an existing code, if you're interested.

Comment: @werediver Assuming the underlying task is a network request, utilising NSURLSession, the number of maximum concurrent requests can be set there. There is no compelling reason to limit the number of concurrently _submitted_ tasks (unless resource timeouts become an issue, but this is set to hours) - but there is certainly a way to accomplish this, too.

Comment: @werediver Yes, I am interested in your implementation - perhaps you can post a gist? ;)

Comment: @werediver Ya we all are interested to know what might be the proper solution for this situation.

Comment: @G.Abhisek Well, take the approach above and add error handling and cancellation. Then it is production ready - unless you really have to load thousands of images, in which case you need something bigger (a download manager, managing a persistent list of download tasks, putting tasks automatically in background, implementing `pause`, `continue`, etc, etc).

Comment: I've prepared a demo for those who are interested. Limited concurrent execution and completion handler as a barrier: https://gist.github.com/werediver/a7cc14177f67e52ff67fbeaf37acb55c

Comment: @werediver Nice! See also here: [TaskQueue](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/3d7523559350784afca88d502ad5a4d8) - which is part of [FutureLib](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/FutureLib) and supports _asynchronous_ tasks, where a task has a signature `() -> Future<T>`.  The TaskQueue implementation can be easily tweaked for tasks which signal its completion through completion handlers, though.