# Download array of images as byte array and convert to images

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, image, asynchronous

```
 for i in 0..<array.count
    {
        let escapedString = array[i].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
        var c = ""
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Alamofire.request("url&mfileName=\(escapedString!)").responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result{
                case .success(let data) :
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    c = json["imageBase64"].stringValue
                    if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: c , options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                        let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)!
                        //self.docimages.append(image!)
                        self.docimages.append(image)
                    }
                    break

                case .failure(let error) :
                    print(error)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have an array of image paths. I have to make an API call to get the byte array of each image. After getting the array i have to add it to array of images .

The problem is images are not downloaded in the same order as the initial array. Is there any way i can download the images in the same order as the initial array .

Comment: If you need them done in order, one by one you can use a serial queue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908183/downloading-images-serially-in-a-serial-queue-very-slow. otherwise use a dictionary and a use dispatch groups to know when all requests have completed, in the dictionary use the url as they key and image as the value

Comment: the problem is i have to know which image corresponds to which byte array.

Comment: thats why you use a dictionary, to map url to image received. if you download one by one using serial queue then you dont have to, but it would be much slower

Comment: I got it guys . You can achieve this by using completion handlers. Thanks everyone for your helping mind.

Answer (score 1):

you can use OperationQueue with [AsyncBlockOperation](https://github.com/devxoul/AsyncBlockOperation)
to force each image to compete before other begin to download please check the image

[image]

Example

```
     let queue = OperationQueue()

        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        downloadImage(path: "path1")
        downloadImage(path: "path2")
        downloadImage(path: "path3")
        downloadImage(path: "path4")
        downloadImage(path: "path5")

func downloadImage(path:String){

    queue.addOperationWithAsyncBlock { op in

        Alamofire.request(path).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let data) :
                let json = JSON(data)
                c = json["imageBase64"].stringValue
                if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: c , options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                    let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)!
                    //self.docimages.append(image!)
                    self.docimages.append(image)
                    op.complete()

                }
                break

            case .failure(let error) :
                print(error)
                break
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I added example may it help you @FaheemRahman
don't forget to add pod 'AsyncBlockOperation' in podfile

Comment: I tried this, but this is giving me the same response.

Comment: wired are you sure you use         queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

Comment: I got it. You can do it by using completion handler

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. There are multiple ways to do this. But here, I will explain to you the simplest way.

Here, you are making a mistake. You need to create a `Custom Class` like below.

**STEP: 1**

```
class ImageHolder {
   var index : Int
   var imagePath : String
   var image : UIImage?
   init(index : Int, imagePath : String){
      self.index = index
      self.imagePath = imagePath
   }
}
```

**STEP: 2**
Now, using for loop, you will have **Class Object** with **Index & ImagePath** reside in it.

**STEP: 3**
The last step, you just need to assign an UIImage just recently downloaded to this class object.

Comment: It is depending on the image size, so I have suggested you this way.

Comment: this cannot be used because i have to download byte array forall image path first and after that i have to convert the byte array to images.

Comment: First, you require to create an array of ImageHolder class objects then need to download byte array and then convert it to image. You need to replace 'self.docimages.append(image)' to imageHolderObj.image = image

Comment: I got it. You can do it by using completion handler

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can download the images in the same order using following method

```
//Declare the Variables Globally
var imageDownloadArrayString = [String]() 
var imageDownloadArray = [UIImage]()
var imageUrl : [URL] = []

// Put the your image path
for imageUrls in imagePathArray {  // put your image path array
  //self.imageDownloadArrayString.append(imageUrls)  // imagePathArray in String
  self.imageUrl.append((URL(string:imageUrls)! as NSURL) as URL)
}

//Download the images

DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
 for url in self.imageUrl {
    let image = try! UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))
    self.imageDownloadArray.append(image!) 
  }
}
```

This imageDownloadArray contains order of images. Any Doubt please ask me? This code Works for me!

Comment: I think  UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url)) in the main thread will make lag in UI

Comment: I don't think that's happens,I haven't faced that issue

Comment: can you sent the your image Array. I will Check

Comment: Because I am already face that same issue. This is solution for that problem

Comment: @VigneshJ My image array is actually array containing imagepath. First i have to convert to byte array and then i have to convert it to images . As shown in the above code. I think this can be done by NSoperationqueue.But i tried and failed. can anyone help

Comment: I got it. You can do it by using completion handler